# Get the value of a variable outside a function

Tags: javascript, firebase

How can I get the value of the variable 'clickedName' outside the function 'getClickedName()'?

```
var clickedUidName = firebase.database().ref('users/' + clickedRefUid + '/name');
       clickedUidName.on('value', function getClickedName(snapshot){
       var clickedName = snapshot.val();
       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var clickedUidName = firebase.database().ref('users/' + clickedRefUid + '/name');
clickedUidName.on('value', function getClickedName(snapshot) {
  var clickedName = snapshot.val();
  //call your function here
  myfunction(clickedName);
});

function myfunction(clickedName){
   // do something with clickedName
}
```

Comment: Hello again, how can I console.log the 'clickedName' value outside the function?

Comment: you need to `console.log` in `myfunction`. because this will called after the value to `clickedName` arrived.

Comment: @AagamJain How do we get the value outside `function myfunction(clickedName){
   // do something with clickedName
}//here`